# amazon aws instance blocks outbound http requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, node.js

I have an Amazon account with ec2 instances. we have a client which we need to interact with using soap. However, Amazon only lets us run X about of queries, and then we can not issue more from that process.
To be sure, we've created a simple module, which is constantly blocked after 30 attempts or less. this (very simple) module run without an issue on any local machine we tried, and always fail on any Amazon ec2 instance no matter the size.
We use NodeJS for the web interface, and the test script is an independent script.
Anyone got this error?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting rate limited by the API you're hitting, not AWS. There's no mechanism in AWS that would do this, especially not after allowing some to go through first, and especially not after a mere 30 queries.

Comment: The API works fine on local machines and on rackspace. aws is the only place where we get this issue.

Comment: @donald That doesn't mean they aren't limiting you. Entirely possible they're limiting EC2's IP ranges due to abuse. AWS definitely doesn't go around rate limiting your SOAP requests on their end.

Comment: It's only one host - the client's server.

Comment: I'd ask your client, then.

Comment: Spoke to Amazon, they've fixed it, seems they have some filter on that...

Comment: @donald can you provide more info?